# How to add Multidex support to Android d8.bat commandline

Tags: android, delphi, android-d8

I'm using Androids d8 compiler from Delphi, and i need to enable MultiDex. In Android Studio you add the following to your Gradle file:

defaultConfig {
minSdkVersion 14
targetSdkVersion 22
multiDexEnabled true
}

but as i am using Delphi i cannot do that. How do i turn on MultiDex support to the commandline tool d8.bat?

Comment: Is this not yours?: https://github.com/helgovic/MultiDex-for-Delphi

Comment: yes, but that is the old dexer dx.bat

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's really simple. Just add this option:

```
    --min-api 21
```

Why this information is so hard to come by, i don't understand. I hate when people don't document their stuff.

Comment: Does "just add this option" mean to the d8 command? You should make this clearer