# how to create multil dex files from jar with d8.bat

Tags: android, command, dex

i use command "d8 class.jar" to make dex file and cause Exception: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 96852 > 65536)

i do not find d8 command options like "multiDexEnabled=true" to make more dex files at one time

how to create multil dex files from jar with d8.bat

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68219149/how-to-add-multidex-support-to-android-d8-bat-commandline